# How can find the fourth derivative of C(x,t)? I Want to find the derivative with respect to X with Leibniz's rule.

Tags: derivatives

Equation C(x,t) is an Oscillatory integral that is obtained by solving a partial differential equation with Fourier transform. The partial differential equation is ill-posed in inverse time.

$$C(x,t)= \int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}B(\omega,y)e^{i\omega x}dy d\omega $$
$$B(\omega,y)= f(y)*e^{-i\omega y+iv\omega t+tD\omega^2+tE\omega^4} $$
$$\partial^4 C/\partial x^4= ? $$

Comment: Welcome to this new forum. Please listen, you have to show your own effort to the question. Then others will help you. So please write something more which you tried